# My horizontalscrollview is stretching my imagebuttons when I use scale:fitxy

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

My xml works just fine on the android studios nexus 7 and nexus 10 emulators and the xml looks fine running on my nexus 4. But when I run it on a 7 inch tablet it stretches my image in the y direction only (in landscape activity) and doesn't keep the aspect ratio. I've tried 2 different 7 inch tablets with the same result.I think I've tried changing layoutwidth and layoutheight to just about every possible combination. I also have the same scaling issue if I try it with a imageview instead of an imagebutton. I googled and googled and tried everything but haven't found a solution that works for me. Please help me...

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="goToLab101" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu2"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:onClick="goToPeriodicTable" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="goToLab102"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:src="@drawable/fountainselector"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu5comingsoon"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:onClick="goToLab103"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu6"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: try flipping these values android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your same image drawables in drawable-large-xhdpi for 7 inch tablet support

Comment: Yes, I had tried adding larger image files to the xhdpi folder but this didn't 'seem' to fix my problem. My issue was my source image wasn't big enough to keep the aspect ratio when scaled to fit XY. The reason that adding a bigger image didn't fix my issue at first was that I needed to 'clean' my project for it to start using the bigger image when running on my device. Unfortunately I didn't clean my project until after I spent hours trying to fix the issue.